# Duplicate Disks Showing in "My PC" Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vss

I've got a Server 2012 R2 VM running as an SMB file host (VHDx on Host side.) Recently, I noticed that both the system disk and the data disk have duplicates showing in "My PC":

[image: duplicate disks]

I: is a clone of C:, and J: is a clone of D:. They both appear to be some kind of read-only snapshot. i.e. if I add/delete data to/from C: it doesn't show up in I:.

The [`SUBST`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx) command shows nothing.

Shadow copies are disabled for the disks (and was never turned on by me.)

I did recently enable the Data Deduplication service for D:, but this may be a coincidence.

Internet searches have not revealed any info about this situation (searching for "duplicate disks" is filled with unrelated problems.)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tracked it down to being a shadow copy of the disks. How, if I never enabled it?

My only guess is that the shadow copy set was created when I installed the Data Deduplication service, though I can find no evidence of this elsewhere on the internet.

Attempting to remove the shadows with `vssadmin` failed with error `Snapshots were found, but they were outside of your allowed context. Try removing them with the backup application which created them.` (As a note, no backup software was or ever has been running on this server.)

Eventually this led [here](https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb/121604) which has the solution:

> Launch an elevated command prompt on the Agent machine(s) involved and
>   type the following:
>
> `diskshadow <enter>`
>
> `list shadows all <enter>`
>
> `delete shadows set  {id of shadow to be deleted if selective deletion
>   is to be performed}<enter>`
>
> OR
>
> `delete shadows all {if all shadows are to be deleted}`
>
> This will delete the corrupted shadow copies.